# Is $Th(\mathbb{Z}[x])$ uncountably categorical?

Tags: logic, model-theory

Consider $T=Th(\mathbb{Z}[x])$ in the language $L = \{0,1,+,\times,deg(), \circ\}$ where $0,1,+$ and $\times$ have their usual interpretations, $deg()$ is a unary function symbol which gives the degree of a polynomial and $\circ$ is a binary  function symbols where (if $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are polynomials) $$ p(x)\circ q(x) = p(q(x))$$ and if $p(x)$ is a "constant", then $$p(x) \circ q(x) = p(x)$$

Clearly, $T$ is not countably categorical since it has $\aleph_0$ many $1-$types definable without parameters. However, I cannot figure out whether the theory is uncountably categorical.

Thank you.

Comment: What are the one types ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Equivalence classes of elements satisfying the same formulas with one free variable.

Comment: @Dave Yah ok I mean in this case what are the one types he mentions in the question.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: Are you asking for all of the one types or the reason why $T$ is not $\aleph_0$ categorical?

Comment: Okay, sorry, I misread your question. I imagine all positive integers can be distinguished by formulas $n = 1 + \dots + 1$.

Comment: @Dave: Yes, that's why the theory is not $\aleph_0$ categorical.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think this theory is bi-interpretable with the integers (think of encoding sequences of integers as integers). That should make its categoricity equivalent to that of integers. But don't quote me on that. :)

Comment: One thing I would like to know is can you define an ordering, say of the integers ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: I added an answer to this question. We can indeed define an ordering on the integers.

Comment: @KyleGannon: You don't need that (degree function), actually. It turns out that the natural numbers are definable in integers: they are exactly the sums of four squares. That is the famous Lagrange's four square theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you contain the arithmetic of the integers you can pick some infinite family of primes and say that an element of degree $0$ is divisible by those primes and not any other primes. This gives uncountably many types over a countable set, so  the theory is not $\aleph_0$ stable and thus not uncountably categorical.

Comment: Ahh! yes! We can simply define primes (up to multiplication by a unit) because of degree 0. Thank you. (We could also get rid of the $deg()$ function and still do this because of $\circ$).

Comment: You could also play the same game with polynomial primes, $x-a$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a response to Rene Schipperus's comment asking whether or not we can define an ordering on the integers in this structure. It turns out that we can.

We say that $P(x)$, i.e. "x is positive", holds on an element of our structure if $(\exists y)(deg(y)=x)$.

Note that $x$ is an "integer" if and only if $deg(x) = 0$.

Now, we say that $x < y \iff (deg(x)=deg(y)=0)\wedge (\exists z)[(P(z)\wedge (z\neq 0) \wedge  (x+z =y)]$

Comment: Oh of course the degree function gives the positive elements. Well the theory is unstable so has $2^{\kappa}$ many models in all uncountable $\kappa$.